# Is it possible to turn off the GPS on the 6D when its main switch is set to off?

Tags: gps, canon-6d

While the built in GPS in the 6D is wonderful to have, it drains the battery in a matter of days if left enabled. This is of course expected, but the GPS continues to update the position when the power is off. I can understand why the GPS remains on when idle (acquiring a GPS lock can take a while), but I'd like it to turn off with the camera.

Is it possible to configure it to turn off when the camera's power switch is set to off? I couldn't find that setting in the camera or in the manual, but it seems like a sensible option that should exist.

Comment: according to http://forums.usa.canon.com/t5/EOS/6D-GPS-Drains-battery-when-idle/td-p/13439 you have to disable the GPS (via a menu setting) to get it to turn off and stop draining the battery

Comment: No, you can't, according to all the reviews and articles I've read so far. It's really silly. It would be possible for Canon to remedy this in a firmware update, though, but I wouldn't get my hopes up high.

Comment: Yes you can, like the first comment above says. It will simply not be off if you turn the camera off, but if you turn it off in the menu it will stay off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The GPS of the Canon 6D does not automatic turn-off while the camera is off by design. In that case  you need to disable it by the menu setting (what a shame Canon). Another option, less elegant, is remove the battery everytime you won't use the camera. This is a good practice that not everybody does but in your case it will help too. Maybe in a future Canon could fix this by a firmware update. Will see.